# Connected Router - newly routed page contains additional data

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux

I have the below file structure for index.jsx wherein AppContainer component consists of Header, props.children, and footer. AppContainer is the child for Connected Router Component. A Component BookReader is defined in the route which opens up on a new page. I want to load only the data of that component and not the header and footer along with it .

index.js

```
<Provider>
  <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
   <AppContainer>
     <Switch>
       <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
       <Route A/>
       <Route B/>
       <Route C/>
       <Route path="/read" component={BookReader}/> // component that opens in a new page
       <Route path="*" component={ErrorPage}/>
     </Switch>
   </AppContainer>
 </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>
```

AppConatiner.jsx

```
class AppContainer extends Component () {
 render(){
   return(
    <div>
     <Header/>
     {props.children}
     <Footer/>
    </div>
   )}
  }
```

is there a way to define the route for BookReader separately such that BookReader should only load the correspondent data and not the additional data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

Move `AppContainer` inside switch and have a simple nested route.

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/router-issue-fixed-hkm2s?file=/src/App.js) (option 1)

```js
<Provider>
  <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/read" component={BookReader} />
      <Route path="/">
        <AppContainer>
          <Route A />
          <Route B />
          <Route C />
        </AppContainer>
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>
```

**Option 2**

Render the `AppContainer` as a Route. Inside `AppContainer` do all the routes.

```js
     <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/read" component={BookReader} />
          <Route path="/" component={AppContainer} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
```

Comment: Have tried it, will get the error Router should have only one child element and if I enclose in a div and use it, the children consisting of header and footer both are loading along with it

Comment: Yes, it works, but there were two routes which I failed to update, have updated it in the question, when those are included especially the path="*" the Error Component is also loaded when the App Container loads.

Comment: have used another Switch block inside the AppContainer and that is working Hope it is correct -                                                                                
     ```<Switch>
    <Route path="/read" component={BookReader}/>                                                                                                
     <AppContainer>
       <Switch>
         <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
         <Route A/>
         <Route B/>
         <Route C/>
         <Route path="*" component={ErrorPage}/>
       </Switch>
    </AppContainer>
   </Switch>```

Comment: awesome... glad to hear that ... if the answer helped please consider to upvote and accept the answer..